# Expression Language access a map value by key

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am iterating a list named `listEvents` (of type `List<String>`) in JSP using `<c:forEach>` tag. Inside the for loop I need to display a value from a `HashMap<String,String>`. The key for the hashmap will be the element in the list. Please find below the code snippet.

```
<c:forEach items="${listEvents}" var="listEvent" varStatus="eventCount">
     <c:out value="${eventMap[listEvent]}</
</c:forEach>
```

When I try with the above code, I am getting

> PropertyNotFoundException ["Key" property not found on java.lang.String].

How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems that eventMap is a String, and not a Map. Show us how this map is constructed and added as an attribute.

Comment: Thank you..I am passing the map as <%@attribute> to the jsp. By default the attribute takes String type as input. Since I am passing HashMap I need to explicitly set the type as java.util.HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do it:

```
         <c:forEach var="listEvent" items="${eventMap}" varStatus="eventCount">
                ${listEvent.value}
         </c:forEach>
```

To access the key add this line:

```
         ${listEvent.key}
```